# compute $\lim_{t\to \infty }t^{(x+1)}e^{-t}$

Tags: real-analysis

This is my way. I suppose $x\neq -1$ (the case $x=-1 $ is obvious).

$$t^{(x+1)}e^{-t}=e^{(x+1)\ln(t)-t}$$

We have that 
$$(x+1)\ln(t)-t=(x+1)\left(\ln(t)-\ln(e^{\frac{t}{x+1}})\right)=(x+1)\left(\ln\left(\frac{t}{e^{\frac{t}{x+1}}}\right)-1\right)$$

Since $\frac{t}{e^{\frac{t}{x+1}}}\underset{t\to\infty }{\longrightarrow }0$,

$$\lim_{t\to \infty }\left((x+1)\left(\ln\left(\frac{t}{e^{\frac{t}{x+1}}}\right)-1\right)\right)=-\infty $$
and thus $$\lim_{t\to \infty }t^{x+1}e^{-t}=0.$$

**Question**

1) Is it correct ?

2) Is there an other way to compute this limit ?

3) Last question, I used the fact that $$\lim_{x\to \infty }e^{u(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to\infty }u(x)}$$
but I don't see why we can do this when $u(x)\to\infty $.

Comment: What about using ratio test ?

Comment: ratio test ? I don't know it for function

Comment: Consider the series whose t th term is $t^{x+1} e^{-t} $ and show this series converges (Using ratio test for series).

Comment: You can make use of L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It's not correct, you only have

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} \frac{t}{e^{\frac{t}{x+1}}} = 0\tag{$\ast$}$$

for $x > -1$. And besides, for $x > -1$, $(\ast)$ is equivalent to what you want to prove.

2) For $x < -1$, we have $\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty} t^{x+1} = 0$, and thus

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} t^{x+1}e^{-t} = \lim_{t\to +\infty} t^{x+1}\cdot \lim_{t\to +\infty} e^{-t} = 0\cdot 0 = 0.$$

For $x + 1 > 0$, let $k = \lceil x+1\rceil$. Then by the exponential series, we know that

$$e^t > \frac{t^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

for all $t > 0$, so

$$0 < t^{x+1}e^{-t} < \frac{(k+1)! t^{x+1}}{t^{k+1}} < \frac{(k+1)!}{t},$$

and the squeeze theorem shows

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} t^{x+1}e^{-t} = 0.$$

3) We can do it because we can continuously extend the exponential function to a bijection $[-\infty,+\infty] \to [0,+\infty]$, so

$$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} e^{(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} u(x)}$$

holds whenever $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} u(x)$ exists in $[-\infty,+\infty]$.